# Two or more active processes in Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, ubuntu-server, server-administration

I have Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS.

I want to run two processes, but at the same time have a "clean" command line.

For example,

process 1: `ping google.com`

process 2: `ping facebook.com`

I tried running them in the background using `&`:

process 1: `ping google.com &`

process 2: `ping facebook.com &`

However, the results of executing commands are displayed in the command line:

[image]

How can I run two processes to leave the command line "clean"?

Comment: What do you mean by "clean command line"?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the "screen" program.

You can create new screen with `screen -S [name]`.
Simply said it just open a new bash where you can run your commands.
If you want to exit the screen just press `Ctrl + A + D`

If you want to resume the screen, just run `screen -r [screen-name]`

The advantage is that you can close you terminal and the screen will continuously running in the background.

For more information check this link out: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-screen-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server